# Determine the integral of $f(x,y,z)=z$ on the region $y^2+z^2=9,x=0,z=0,y=3x$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I believe the integral I want is $\int\int_D\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} z dzdA$
And the bounds for $y$ on $z=0$ are determine by the line $y=3$ and $y=3x$ And the values $x$ takes in this region are $0\to 1$ so I determined the integral to be:

$$\int_0^1\int_{3x}^3\int_0^{\sqrt{9-y^2}} z dzdydx$$

But when I got to evaluate this I end up getting
$$\int_0^1\int_{3x}^3 \sqrt{9-y^2} dzdx$$
$$= \frac{9}{2}\left[\int_0^1 \arcsin(1)-\arcsin(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\arcsin(1))-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\arcsin(x))\right]dx$$

Which I can't solve.

$$\frac{9}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x+\frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi)-\frac{1}{2} 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx=\frac{9}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin x-\frac{1}{2} 2x\sqrt{1-x^2}\, dx$$

Which gives $$\frac{9}{2}[\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2}dx-\int_0^1 \arcsin x dx-\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2} dx]=\frac{9}{2}[\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{2}+1+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{9}{2}(\frac{4}{3})=6$$

Comment: A formatting note: when you're putting equations on their own line, use double dollar signs to invoke "display mode". My edit to a previous version applied this to earlier parts of your post, so you can see how the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have a cylinder cut by a plane.

In light of this, I think I would use a different order of integration, and I would look to make  transformation to cylindrical coordinates.

In Cartesian.

$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt {9-z^2}}\int_0^{\frac {y}{3}} z \ dx \ dy\ dz$

Actually this could be nice in cartesian.

$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\sqrt {9-z^2}} \frac {zy}{3} \ dy\ dz\\
\int_{0}^{3} \frac {z(9-z^2)}{6} \ dz\\
\frac {9z^2}{12} - \frac {z^4}{24} |_0^3\\
\frac {81}{24} = \frac {27}{8}$

In cylindrical

$z = r\cos\theta\\ y = r\sin\theta\\ x = x\\
dz\ dy\ dz = r\ dx\ dr\ d\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{3}\int_0^{\frac {r\sin\theta}{3}} r^2\cos\theta \ dx \ dr\ d\theta\\
\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \int_{0}^{3} \frac {r^3}{3}\sin\theta \cos\theta \ dr\ d\theta\\
\int_{0}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\frac {81}{12}\sin\theta \cos\theta\ d\theta\\
\frac {81}{24} (\sin^2 \theta)|_0^\frac {\pi}{2}\\
\frac {27}{8}$

Comment: did you mean cylindrical coordinates? I thought spherical was $(x,y,z)=(\rho\cos\phi\sin\theta,\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta,\rho\cos\theta)$ And cylindrical is $(x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$

Comment: @AColoredReptile Indeed I did mean cylindrical.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit note: the bulk of this post is based on erroneous material in the question, and does not apply to the correctly evaluated integral.

So, the sticking point here is that expression "$\sin(2\arcsin(t))$", with two cases $t=1$ and $t=x$ appearing. How do we deal with that? We need a double-angle formula: if $\theta=\arcsin t$, then
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = 2t\cos\theta$$
Now, $\cos\theta$ - since $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, we have $\cos^2\theta=1-t^2$. The cosine is one of the square roots of $1-t^2$. Which square root? For that, we note that the standard branch of $\arcsin$ we use to define the real function has values in $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. In that range, $\cos$ is nonnegative - so then $\cos(\arcsin t) = +\sqrt{1-t^2}$ and
$$\sin(2\arcsin t) = 2\sin(\arcsin t)\cos(\arcsin t)=2t\sqrt{1-t^2}$$
Apply this, and we then have an integral of an arcsin, some constants, and an algebraic term. Can you finish it from there?

On second thought - this integral is in error almost from the start. You found the integral of $1\,dz$ in the innermost integral, not the integral of $z\,dz$. Fix that, and all of the irrational parts go away.

I'll leave the rest of this up, since explaining how to deal with those $\sin(2\cdot\arcsin)$ terms has some value.

Comment: Is this a substitution? What do I do with $x$ and $1$?

Comment: $t$ here is a shorthand for "anything we might want to put in there". We can replace it with $1$ to get $\sin(2\arcsin 1)$, or with $x$ to get $\sin(2\arcsin x)$. It's a dummy variable, with no external meaning; I just chose a letter that we weren't using already to avoid confusion.

Comment: Alright I believe I solved it. As $\int \arcsin(x) dx=x\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\int x\sqrt{1-x^2} dx=\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}$. I've edited my solution into the question.

Comment: Hold on a sec - $\frac23x^{\frac32}$ is an antiderivative of $\sqrt{x}$. I think you failed to handle the substitution properly there. The integral in the question is definitely off - subtracting the integral of something positive like $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ should result in a negative term, not $+\frac13$.

Comment: $\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$ let $t=1-x^2$, then $dx=\frac{dt}{-2x}$ thus we have $\frac{-1}{2}\int_0^1\sqrt{t} dt=\frac{-1}{2}[\frac{2}{3}(1-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\big\vert_0^1=\frac{1}{3}$